# How must a query look like for this complex data?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mariadb-10.1, mysql-dependent-subquery

i'm stuck creating a complex query... maybe there is some help out there?? :)
I've a table with device status. An entry is genereated for each device status change.
What i want to have is an output where i can see the lastest per date of all devices - for all dates containing in the table. in this exampel 04.05.2021 - 06.05.2021.
i want to use it for a dashboard.

Can anyone help me out?

Here is an example how the table is looking like:
Table of Device-Changes:

| ID | DEVICEID | CHANGEDON | PREVALUE | POSTVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 40 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 21 | 41 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 22 | 42 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 23 | 43 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 24 | 44 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 25 | 45 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 26 | 46 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 27 | 47 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 28 | 48 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 29 | 40 | 05.05.2021 15:00 | ON | OFF |
| 30 | 40 | 05.05.2021 16:00 | OFF | RECOV |
| 31 | 40 | 05.05.2021 17:00 | RECOV | WAIT |
| 32 | 41 | 06.05.2021 09:00 | ON | OFF |
| 33 | 41 | 06.05.2021 10:00 | OFF | WAIT |
| 35 | 40 | 06.05.2021 11:00 | WAIT | ON |

The output what i want to achieve is the follwoing:

| LATESTSTATPERDATE | DEVICEID | CHANGEDON | PREVALUE | POSTVALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04.05.2021 | 40 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 41 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 42 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 43 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 44 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 45 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 46 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 47 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 04.05.2021 | 48 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 40 | 05.05.2021 17:00 | RECOV | WAIT |
| 05.05.2021 | 41 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 42 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 43 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 44 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 45 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 46 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 47 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 05.05.2021 | 48 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 40 | 06.05.2021 11:00 | WAIT | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 41 | 06.05.2021 10:00 | OFF | WAIT |
| 06.05.2021 | 42 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 43 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 44 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 45 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 46 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 47 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |
| 06.05.2021 | 48 | 04.05.2021 13:00 | - | ON |

```
WORKING SOLUTION FOR ME:
With
    Query1 As (
        Select
            *
        From
            devices
    )
select 
    first.deviceid as Device,
    first.changedon as Date,
    first.changedon1 as SubDate,
    first.prevalue,
    first.postvalue
from (
Select
    Concat(Date(devices.changedon), " 23:59:59") As changedon,
    Query1.deviceid,
    Query1.changedon As changedon1,
    Query1.prevalue,
    Query1.postvalue
From
    devices Left Join
    Query1 On Query1.changedon <= devices.changedon
Group By
    devices.changedon,
    Query1.deviceid
order by devices.changedon DESC, changedon1 DESC
) as first
group by Date,Device
order by Date ASC
```

Comment: You're looking for `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: hi pavel, i've tried to make this happen with "GROUP BY" but wasn'T really successfull.:( can you give me some hints? the problem was, that i need every device in all dates...
the table needs a join on himself... and i don't know how to work this out...

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Does `id_1 > id_2` always matches `date_1 >= date_2`?

Comment: @FeLoN: after 3mins you really didn't study `GROUP BY`. You need to combine group by for `deviceID` a `Y-m-d` date. Please add your own effort.

Comment: the Version of mysq is:l  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.47-MariaDB

Comment: That's bad, CTE and window functions are not available.

Comment: @Akina the "id" from the first table is only generated for the entry itself and not in a relationship with the other data.

Comment: @Akina when i update mariadb to a newer version would it be possible to achieve it? and how must i do it? sorry for those questions, but i'm not familiar with CTE or window functions.

Comment: Step 1. Get list of devices (`SELECT DISTINCT device_id`) from 1st copy of table. 2. Get list of dates from 2nd copy of table. 3. CROSS JOIN them, obtain all possible pairs (date, device). 4. Join 3rd copy of table by "the same device and date not above". Group. Find according pair value for last row not above by date. 5. Join 4th copy, select complete row by found device and date.

Comment: @pavel thank you for your hints :) i'll try to make it with GROUP BY maybe i missed something, but my group by rules were not working out.
i've made a query which shows me the correct status for a certain date, but i wasn'T able to combine the table with itself to achieve the results.
i wasn't aware, that i can do this with group by

Comment: *when i update mariadb to a newer version would it be possible to achieve it?* You may do this on current version - but the solution will be **TOO** complex. IF you'll upgrade to at least 10.2.1 the solution will be much easier.

Comment: @Akina WOW thanks for helping :) do i need seperate temporary tables for that, or could this be handled in "ONE" query? i just ask in which way i should do more research :)